# How to use pycdc for python 3.9.x

Tags: python, python-3.9, decompiler, pyc

I am trying to decompile some .pyc files and after some research, I found that the only usable tool for python 3.9 is pycdc (uncompyle6 and decompyle3 are only supported up to 3.8), though I can't seem to get it to work, I tried `bin\pycdc [PATH_TO_FILE]`, `pycdc [PATH_TO_FILE]` and `python pycdc [PATH_TO_FILE]` and I get errors. (I was in the pycdc directory when I ran these commands)

`\bin\pycdc [PATH_TO_FILE]`: `bin\pycdc : The module 'bin' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module bin'.`

`pycdc [PATH_TO_FILE]`: `The term 'pycdc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` (I tried `.\pycdc`, `\bin\pycdc`, and `.\bin\pycdc` to see if there is any difference, same error)

`python pycdc [PATH_TO_FILE]`: `Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\pycdc-master\pycdc': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`